# Mapzen Search - Zoom to Search Pin

Tags: leaflet, mapzen

I am developing a Leaflet map that includes a MapZen address search. I cant find any information on how to zoom in on the search pin after an address is selected and the map pans to the pin. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you,

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapzen Leaflet Geocoder (which is part of mapzen.js) doesn't offer  zoom level change by default when the result's geometry type is point. However, you can listen to the events that Geocoder element fires, execute `setZoom`. You can check all the events that Mapzen Leaflet Geocoder fires here: https://github.com/mapzen/leaflet-geocoder#events

This is the example snippet listening to `select` event, change the zoom level of the map.

```
var map = L.Mapzen.map('map');
map.setView([0,0], 13);

var geocoder = L.Mapzen.geocoder();
geocoder.addTo(map);

var desiredZoomLevel = 17;

wgeocoder.on('select', function (e) {
map.setZoom(desiredZoomLevel);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, that seems to have disabled panToPoint though, so for some reason it zooms to the center of the map instead of to the selected location.

Comment: Update: Sometimes it works, sometimes it zooms and doesn't pan to the point, very confusing!

Comment: that sounds frustrating. if you can set up the jsfiddle showing the problem you are dealing with, it would help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at mapzen.js? It's a Leaflet extension that provides a search box that autozooms to the selected result.

https://mapzen.com/documentation/mapzen-js/

https://mapzen.com/documentation/mapzen-js/search/

Comment: Yeah, I have looked at the documentation for them. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see an option to control zoom when a search result is selected. I only see the option for 'panToPoint' being enabled or disabled.